# Reading wrong data when indexing a nested array

Tags: system-verilog

I'm implementing a dcache in a pipeline processor.
My dcache is a 2-way associative with 2 words per block and 8 indexes
This is how I initialized my cache structure.

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic [25:0] tag;
  logic valid, dirty;
  word_t [1:0] data;
} block_t;

typedef struct packed {
  block_t [1:0] way;
} dcache_t;

dcache_t [7:0] cache;
```

So to access a word: cache[i].way[j].data[k]

I can write to cache fine.

`index`, `way` and `sel` are variables that use combination logic to determine where to index.

So for example, this line is in my `always_ff` register for the cache.

```
cache[index].way[way].data[sel] = ccif.dload[CPUID];
```

After the above line of code, the following gets stored into cache 
for `index = 6`, `way = 0`, `sel = 0`

```
cache[6].way[0].data[0] <== 0x01234567
```

and after the next clock cycle the following for `index = 6`, `way = 0`, `sel = 1`

```
cache[6].way[0].data[1] <== 0x89ABCDEF
```

Since I load two words at a time.

...but when I read from it using `index = 6`, `way = 0`, `sel = 1`

```
dcif.dmemload = cache[index].way[way].data[sel];
```

The following gets read from my cache

```
dcif.dmemload <== 0xCDEF0123
```

I get wrong value and don't know why, since the value in cache is still the same and hasn't changed.

This is the current state of a section of my cache at the time of reading

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| index |  data[1]   |  data[0]   |
+-------+------------+------------+
|     6 |  89ABCDEF  |  01234567  |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Any ideas? I'm confused because my indexing works fine when writing but something weird happens when reading

Edit: the value read isn't always offset by 2 bytes.
I'm not sure if I have too many nested arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in ModelSim/Questa that is fixed in the next release.

The solution is to not make the entire nested array all **packed**. You probably did not mean to have your cache packed anyways. You should not pack your arrays unless you need to access the whole array as a single integral value.

```
dcache_t cache[7:0];
```

Comment: You're right I don't need my whole cache packed, changing the index part of the cache to unpacked as you mentioned fixed my issue. Thanks!